# Pytorch argmax across multiple dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 4D tensor, and I would like to get the argmax across the last two dimensions. `torch.argmax` only accepts integers as the "dim" argument, not tuples.

How can I accomplish this?

Here's what I had in mind, but I can't figure out how to match up the dimensions of my two "indices" tensors. `original_array` is shape [1, 512, 37, 59].

```
max_vals, indices_r = torch.max(original_array, dim=2)
max_vals, indices_c = torch.max(max_vals, dim=2)
indices = torch.hstack((indices_r, indices_c))
```

Comment: What's the shape of `original_array`?

Comment: 1 x 512 x 37 x 59

Comment: Does `max_vals, indices = original_array.view(1, 512, -1).max(dim=-1)` help you? You'd have a `(1 x 512)` indices tensor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others mentioned, its best to flatten the last two dimensions and apply argmax

```
original_array = torch.rand(1, 512, 37, 59)
original_flatten = original_array.view(1, 512, -1)
_, max_ind = original_flatten.max(-1)
```

.. you will get the linear index of the maximum values. In case you want the 2D indecies of the maximum values, you can do "unflatten" the indecies using the number of columns

```
# 59 is the number of columns for the (37, 59) part
torch.stack([max_ind // 59, max_ind % 59], -1)
```

this will give you a `(1, 512, 2)` where each last 2 dim contains 2D coordinates.

Comment: And how does one index `original_array` with `max_ind`? I tried `original_array[:, max_ind]` and it gave me the random numbers instead of the max ones (close to 0.999).

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the last two dimensions with [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html) and apply [`torch.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmax.html) on it:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(2,3,100,100)
>>> x.flatten(-2).argmax(-1)
tensor([[2660, 6328, 8166],
        [5934, 5494, 9717]])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my application, I need to be able to index `original_array` and retain its original dimensions. I think that flattening these dimensions would not allow me to do what I need to do.